# Downgrade firefox to 8

Tags: firefox, gwt, ubuntu, gxt, windowbuilder

I'm trying to run windowbuilder Pro in eclipse, but when I try, it says I'm running Firefox 10 and the debugger only supports up to firefox 8.

So how do I downgrade my firefox to 8? I'm running Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 10 works now with the plugin.

But you could also get a portable version of firefox.
This way you can test with also older version of firefox.

check out:
http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

under Other version you can select different versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck on Firefox, yes .. you will have to downgrade.
You could try Chrome though ..

Comment: that's funny :) I've never heard of this kind of behavior before, well then lucky you